# Ionic native network no found

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, networking, connection

Why the ionic network only detects my connection once and when the status changes should I reload the page? I want it to show me online or offline in the console without reloading the page but it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. As a general rule, please post code of what you have tried so far. It will help you get better results and reduce the amount of down/close votes.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is online or offline using

```
if (navigator.onLine) {
  console.log('online');
} else {
  console.log('offline');
}
```

And for live checking us

```
window.addEventListener('offline', function(e) { console.log('offline'); });

window.addEventListener('online', function(e) { console.log('online'); });
```

Comment: NOTE: This solution will result in a memory leak since the events will continue to fire even when the page is exited.

the function should be explicitly named and then then event listener removed in the exit method.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent memory leaks, when developing in the ionic framework, it is like so:

```
_logOffLine = (e: any) => {
   console.log('offline', e);
}

_logOnLine = (e: any) => {
   console.log('online', e);
}

ionViewDidEnter(): void {
   window.addEventListener('offline', this._logOffLine);
   window.addEventListener('online', this._logOnLine);
}

ionViewDidLeave(): void {
   window.removeEventListener('offline', this._logOffLine);
   window.removeEventListener('online', this._logOnLine);
}
```